# has been and is

Tags: grammaticality

Can you please let me know the scenarios justifying the usage of below 2 sentences?

1. Please let me know whether the activity has been completed.
2. Please let me know whether the activity is completed.

Kind regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 1):

The first example uses the perfect tense. It has a focus on the fact that the activity is currently in the completed state based on something that happened in the past.

You would use the first example if you are enquiring about whether somebody has completed the activity, and as a result it is now complete.

The second example uses a simple copula. It focuses on the current state of the activity being completed, but does not infer that a past event made it this way.

You would use the second example if you are enquiring about whether the activity is currently in a completed state - but not interested in whether it transitioned from being not complete to being completed, or whether it was always in a completed state.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I came across a few articles that avoids "is". For example: Activity completed yesterday. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @KumarLakshmanan if you said "Let me know whether the activity completed yesterday." Then you are using "completed" as a verb (intransitive) and "activity" as the subject, so you are implying that the activity completed itself. This is fine if the activity is a long-running thing that stops by itself when it's done.